# Linq: How to use EntityLists to do a join on a lookup field?

Tags: linq

I have 2 lists, one list contains a lookup to another.

I have used SPMetal to generate entity.cs based on this article: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b0c1cd0d-fe82-444e-a16e-7d3fb7d38eca/join-lists-with-linq--sh.aspx

I don't think I need to go the object LINQ route, as in the article because I have a lookup field on which I want to base the join.

I've gotten this far:

```
EntityDataContext site = new EntityDataContext(this.SiteURL);
site.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

EntityList<ListA> listAItems = site.GetList<ListA>(ListAName);
EntityList<ListB> listBItems = site.GetList<ListB>(ListBName);
```

This works so far and gives 2 flat EntityLists for both Sharepoint Lists.

From this point on, how would I create a query to just join, based on the lookup field?

UPDATE:

If I was doing it in SQL, this is the statement I would be writing:

```
Select [fields] from table1 AA inner join table2 BB on AA.lookupfield = AA.Title/ID where BB.field = $inputFromUser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of [blog post](http://malikhan.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/new-features-of-list-in-sharepoint-2010-part-12/) you can find how to join and query two lists.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: That's not a join, that is a select with a where clause. I am talking about a select from table A inner join table B on A.pkid = B.fkid. Something like this....

Comment: Found this solution that has some great examples: http://solutionizing.net/2009/04/30/join-sharepoint-lists-with-linq/

Comment: Well it's ok if your lists are small, but you can get performance hit if they are large, beacuse you retreaving all items from both lists and then doing **join** - not the best way, better think about using lookup field